# Как реализовать user-friendly web-интерфейс для выполения различных запросов к БД?

Tags: sql, веб-программирование, поиск-программ

Каким образом можно организовать простой и понятный интерфейс взаимодействия с существующей базой данных (группы, пользователи в этих группах, покупки пользователями и т.д.) для получения каких-либо данных?

Пользователи - обычные пользователи, не имеющие представления о select запросах или каких-то инструментах работы с БД, форма отчета - не определена.

Цель - дать инструмент, чтобы пользователи могли получать нужные им данные. Например, количество покупок пользователем или группой за неделю, месяц, какие-то показатели, основанные на времени и т.д. и т.п. По сути, возможность выполнения селект запросов с обыкновенными фильтрами, группировками, агрегатными функциями.

Comment: а что Вы хотите увидеть в ответе?

Comment: Пускай таблицу.

Comment: я про ответ на Ваш вопрос. Он ( вопрос ) слишком размытый и с большой вероятностью его могут закрыть из-за того что неясно что нужно автору вопроса. (Разработка JS компонентов для построения запроса, готовые комплексные компоненты и их примеры, дизайн). Я бы посоветовал Вам конкретизировать вопрос и возможно разбить его на ряд нескольких вопросов, которые касаются конкретных аспектов фронтенд/бекенд/sql/общие конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понимаю, такой инструмент имеется, например, платформа визуализации данных базы QlickView.

Comment: Добавил вам к вопросу метку "поиск-программ". Почитайте описание этой метки, возможно вы захотите или дополнить вопрос, или убрать метку.

Comment: Проблема в том что форма отчета не стандартизирована. Хотелось бы построить какой-то легкий и очевидный конструктор запросов к БД, который будет понятен простому пользователю и в то же время будет достаточно мощным.

Comment: @spammm, не хочу Вас обидеть, но по моему Вы не расчитали силы для такой задачи. Одно дело это DataGrid c фильтрами по одной таблице, другое мощный конструктор запросов. Это не самая лёгкая задача и я думаю решение такой задачи выходит за рамки одного единственного вопроса на SO.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос:** Каким образом можно организовать простой и понятный интерфейс взаимодействия с существующей базой данных.

**Ответ:** Написать админку.

**Ответ2:** Взять готовую (например http://laraadmin.com/, https://github.com/nodeadmin/nodeadmin, вообще красота https://www.forestadmin.com/lumber/)